# Google Container Engine with external IP, without load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am able to connect to the app running in my pod in Kubernetes, but that was with a load balancer gateway, based on the documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer

Is there any way to run a web server on Google Container Engine without having to pay $18/month for a separate load balancer?

Comment: Did you find a solution to avoid the GCE load balancer?

Comment: Check out https://serverfault.com/questions/801189/expose-port-80-and-443-on-google-container-engine-without-load-balancer

Answer (score 1):

Try using `type: Nodeport` for the service. This will open a port on all your nodes. You can use then direct traffic to that port. Refer: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/